Help identifying a comedy WWII movie set in Europe?
I saw a a comedy WWII movie on MTV in Hungary once and have never been able to find out what it was. I'd appreciate any identification. 
Basically, the plot consists of three guys (who seem to be Stooge-like characters), who are chased by Nazis, starting in a house, and into a large theater (where one plays a mad conductor), through the sewers, into a convent, and finally escape by plane. They hide in closets, in bubble baths, escape in one door and out the other, and get disguises by tricking people into manholes while in the sewer.
The climax comes when the German commandant and a gunner have their plane in sight, and the gunner is about to shoot them down, but the commander gets mad and hits him, and the bullet hits a Nazi plane.
Any help in identification would be great!

This could be the Louis de Funès movie La Grande Vadrouille (AKA Don't Look Now: We're Being Shot At) from 1966. An online description:

During World War II three members of a British bomber crew bail out over Paris and make a frantic escape to the free zone by means of various wild disguises.

The trailer features a mad conductor, a convent and a man hiding in a manhole, and in the climax, the 3 protagonists escape in an airplane.
